# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions about colleges?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which/is there a Stack Exchange site where it would be appropriate for me to ask for opinions or thoughts on colleges I am thinking about attending?

Comment: If you're going STEM, good news--it pretty much doesn't matter.  If you're not going STEM, good news--you can skip college and simply pitchfork your cash into a shredder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Such questions are too localised to one geographic area, are very subjective, and answers are likely to change validity over time.

General 'opinions and thoughts' are best left to discussion forums or chat rooms, not to Question and Answer sites.